# JavaScript Local Primitive Variable Re-assignment in Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, recursion, referential-integrity

I have a recursive function like below

```
function dfs(row, col) {
  if (grid[row][col] === 0) return true;
  let result = grid[row][col] === 2;
  grid2[row][col] = 0;

  let up = down = left = right = true;      // <--- problematic line

  if (row > 0) up = dfs(row-1, col);
  
  if (row < m-1) down = dfs(row+1, col);
  // down === false here
  
  if (col > 0) left = dfs(row, col-1);
  // down === false here still
  
  if (col < n-1) right = dfs(row, col+1);
  // down === true ??  

  return up && down && left && right && result;
}
```

I notice that during execution, at some point `down = dfs(row+1, col)` will assign a `false` value to `down`, but 2 lines below after `right = dfs(row, col+1)` somehow `down` becomes `true` again.

This mutation would make sense to me if `down` was a non-primitive variable like Array or Object and we were passing it around across recursive calls, however it's just a boolean. Furthermore, changing the problematic line to below fixes the problem. (i.e. `down` no longer gets re-assigned to `true`)

```
let up = true, down = true, left = true, right = true;
```

Does anyone know why this re-assignment happens here? Thanks!

Comment: this is really abstract as a question, what is the practical purpose? Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line:

```
let up = down = left = right = true;
```

only declares up. down, left, right are assigned from global scope and can get updated by any recursion step since they are not local variables.

Comment: Oops, how did I forget about that...

Answer (score 1):

That `let` declaration does not do what you think it does. (Well, what I think you think it does.)

The `=` in a `let` (or `var` or `const`) declaration works like this:

```
let a = <expression>;
```

Only one variable is declared, `a`. You can *use* the assignment operator in that `<expression>`, but it will not cause any other variables to be declared. The variables would have to exist in some enclosing scope, or else (if you're not in "strict" mode) they will become implicit global variables.

In your statement,

```
let up = down = left = right = true;
```

the variable `up` is the only one declared. To get what I think you want, you'd need

```
let up, down, left, right;
up = down = left = right = true;
```

That will create all four variables in the current scope, and then the subsequent assignment will make them all `true`.

Comment: Oops, how did I forget about that...